# RealmBaseAdapter with section headers

Tags: android, listview, realm

I'm trying to use the `realm` data store for Android and i'm trying to build an application that shows the user a list of options in a `ListView`, kind of like the users contact list. The first letter for each section (such as A, B, C, etc.) should be a header. Is there a way to achieve this with `RealmBaseAdapter`?

Currently I have it working with `ArrayAdapter` and I simply have an array with values populated but would like to pull data from Realm using its adapter if possible. I know in iOS this is fairly straight forward using the `NSFetchedResultsController`. How do we break up the `RealmResults` into sections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RealmBaseAdapter doesn't work with ExpandableListAdapter (which I am assuming you are using for sections?), so right now your only choice is creating your own implementation. But a RealmResults is also a List so it should work seamlessly with an ArrayAdapter.

You can also see more details here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/978

Comment: Is this in the plans for future? I can do it via the list. But the issue happens to be that when you have a very large list (10,000+ items), its not efficient to do it that way.

Comment: We don't have any current plans, but I can see the use case for a Realm version of the BaseExpandableListAdapter which would be needed for something like this. I have added it to our backlog: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1199

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use:

```
package com.poterion.android.library.adapters

import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter
import io.realm.*

/**
 * @author Jan Kubovy &lt;jan@kubovy.eu&gt;
 */
abstract class RealmExpandableListAdapter<out Group : Any, Item : RealmModel>(
        private val itemGroupsProvider: (Item) -> Collection<Group?>,
        private val groupsProvider: (Collection<Item>) -> List<Group?>,
        private var adapterData: OrderedRealmCollection<Item>?) : BaseExpandableListAdapter() {
    private val listener: RealmChangeListener<OrderedRealmCollection<Item>>?

    protected val groups: List<Group?>
        get() {
            return adapterData?.takeIf { isDataValid }?.let(groupsProvider) ?: emptyList()
        }

    private val isDataValid: Boolean
        get() = adapterData?.isValid == true

    init {
        if (adapterData?.isManaged == false)
            throw IllegalStateException("Only use this adapter with managed list, for un-managed lists you can just use the BaseAdapter")
        this.listener = RealmChangeListener { notifyDataSetChanged() }
        adapterData?.takeIf { isDataValid }?.also { addListener(it) }
    }

    private fun addListener(data: OrderedRealmCollection<Item>) {
        when (data) {
            is RealmResults<Item> -> data.addChangeListener((listener as RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Item>>))
            is RealmList<Item> -> data.addChangeListener((listener as RealmChangeListener<RealmList<Item>>))
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("RealmCollection not supported: " + data.javaClass)
        }
    }

    private fun removeListener(data: OrderedRealmCollection<Item>) {
        when (data) {
            is RealmResults<Item> -> data.removeChangeListener((listener as RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Item>>))
            is RealmList<Item> -> data.removeChangeListener((listener as RealmChangeListener<RealmList<Item>>))
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("RealmCollection not supported: " + data.javaClass)
        }
    }

    override fun getGroupCount(): Int = groups.size

    override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int = adapterData?.takeIf { isDataValid }?.let { data ->
        val g = groups[groupPosition]
        data.filter { g == null || groups(it).contains(g) }.size
    } ?: 0

    override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): Group? = if (groups.size > groupPosition) groups[groupPosition] else null

    override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Item? = children(groupPosition)
        .takeIf { it.size > childPosition }?.get(childPosition)

    override fun notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun children(groupPosition: Int): List<Item> {
        return getGroup(groupPosition)
                    ?.let { g -> adapterData?.takeIf { isDataValid }?.filter { groups(it).contains(g) } } ?: emptyList()
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
class PersonListAdapter(realm: Realm) :
        RealmExpandableListAdapter<String, Person>(
                itemGroupsProvider = { person -> arrayOf(person.group, null) },
                groupsProvider = { people -> people.map { it.group } },
                adapterData = realm.where(Person::class.java)
                        .findAllSortedAsync("lastName", Sort.ASCENDING, "firstName", Sort.ASCENDING)) {

    override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int) = getGroup(groupPosition).id

    override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int) = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).id

    override fun hasStableIds() = true

    override fun getGroupView(groupPosition: Int, isExpanded: Boolean, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        // ... Item View here ...
    }

    override fun getChildView(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int, isLastChild: Boolean,
                              convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        // ... Group View here ...
    }

    override fun isChildSelectable(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int) = true
}
```